# Can i find a solution to creating my own tag in html5 and my tag must be validated in w3c

Tags: html, css

my need is to create this example

```html
<list>
  <child>1</child>
  <child>2</child>
  <child>3</child>
</list>
```

and also i must to be validate this tag in w3c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom elements are invalid and so will not validate using the w3c validator.

> Note that custom element names require a dash to be used in them; they
>   can't be single words.

[- Source: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements)

I assume this requirement is to ensure that you do not attempt to use a name for your elements that may be implemented natively at a later date - all native HTML elements have single word names.

The following example will validate without error but your current code will not.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<title>Validate Custom Tag</title>
</head>
<body>
  <my-list>
    <my-child>1</my-child>
    <my-child>2</my-child>
    <my-child>3</my-child>
  </my-list>
</body>
```

Comment: so the solution is to using a validate element <ul> and <li> ?

Comment: Either that or give your custom elements valid names.

Comment: how i give a valid names ? you mean that <my-list> ?

Comment: The name _must_ contain a hyphen (`-`). Read the quoted text in my answer.

Comment: yes i see it, and let's say I created my element <my-list> and this element is validated by w3c ?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. Copy my example above and paste it in to the validator... https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input